# How to replace elements of different Comboboxes?

Tags: c#, wpf

All I want to do is to replace Combobox elements. Each of Comboboxes is binding on the same Array, so there should not be troubles with it.
**There should be a button, that provides this "Combobox replace" by a click.**
Here is one of Combobox XAML (the second is quite similar):

```
<ComboBox
            x:Name="from"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="4"
            Width="340"
            Height="40"
            Margin="18,0,0,0"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
            DropDownClosed="from_DropDownClosed"
            FontFamily="Montserrat"
            FontSize="20"
            IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Angle}"
            SelectedValue="{Binding Angle[0]}"
            SelectionChanged="from_SelectionChanged" />
```

XAML of 2nd Combobox:

```
<ComboBox
            x:Name="to"
            Grid.Row="2"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="4"
            Width="340"
            Height="40"
            Margin="18,0,0,0"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
            DropDownClosed="to_DropDownClosed"
            FontFamily="Montserrat"
            FontSize="20"
            IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Angle}"
            SelectedValue="{Binding Angle[1]}"
            SelectionChanged="to_SelectionChanged" />
```

My attempt was to change indexes of SelectedItem of Comboboxes. But it works strange.
That way changes the selection of first Combobox on second. But other one doesn't undergo any changes. My code version below (doesn't work correctly):

```
object item1 = from.SelectedItem;
object item2 = to.SelectedItem;

// Replacing them
from.SelectedItem = item2;
to.SelectedItem = item1;
```

The pic of page below:
[Page overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7q5G.png)

Comment: Show xaml for the second combo box.

Comment: Replace how? Do you mean change the selection or what does "replace" mean in this case? How do you replace an item in which `ComboBox` when yoy click the button?

Comment: @mm8 I mean there are two ComboBoxes, that are binded on the same Array. And here is a Button, that provides a Click event, that set ComboBox1 selected value to ComboBox2 and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the `SelectedItem` value is always looking at the `Angle[x]` value.
Try and create 2 separate properties `SelectedItem1` and `SelectedItem2` and bind the `SelectedItem` of each `ComboBox` to the respective property.

I would also advise you to use the `SelectedItem` properties instead of `SelectionChanged` events in order to preserve the MVVM principle (if your event code needs access to `ViewModel` data).

Also, you could use an `ObservableCollection<MyClassOrType>` instead of an array to keep things simpler.

Something like this:

```
private ObservableCollection<MyClassOrType> angle = new ObservableCollection<MyClassOrType>();
public ObservableCollection<MyClassOrType> Angle
{
    get => angle;
    private set => angle = value;
}

private MyClassOrType selected_item_1;
public MyClassOrType SelectedItem1
{
    get => selected_item_1;
    set
    {
        selected_item_1 = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedItem1)); // Notify view of the change
        // Do your from_SelectionChanged code here
    }
}

private MyClassOrType selected_item_2;
public MyClassOrType SelectedItem2
{
    get => selected_item_2;
    set
    {
        selected_item_2 = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedItem2)); // Notify view of the change
        // Do your to_SelectionChanged code here
    }
}
```

`MyClassOrType` is whatever object type you are storing in your collection(int, float, classes
etc.)

Then you can bind your `ComboBox` like this:

```
<ComboBox
  x:Name="from"
  Grid.Column="1"
  Grid.ColumnSpan="4"
  Width="340"
  Height="40"
  Margin="18,0,0,0"
  HorizontalAlignment="Left"
  VerticalAlignment="Center"
  VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
  DropDownClosed="from_DropDownClosed"
  FontFamily="Montserrat"
  FontSize="20"
  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False"
  ItemsSource="{Binding Angle}"
  SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedItem1}" />

<ComboBox
  x:Name="to"
  Grid.Row="2"
  Grid.Column="1"
  Grid.ColumnSpan="4"
  Width="340"
  Height="40"
  Margin="18,0,0,0"
  HorizontalAlignment="Left"
  VerticalAlignment="Center"
  VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
  DropDownClosed="to_DropDownClosed"
  FontFamily="Montserrat"
  FontSize="20"
  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False"
  ItemsSource="{Binding Angle}"
  SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedItem2}" />
```

Next up is your `Button`. In order to preserve the MVVM principle, you should bind to an `ICommand` implementation to execute your code inside your `ViewModel` instead of the view itself seeing as you are manipulating data and not just view properties.

In your button command binding you can do something like:

```
<Button Name="MyButton" Command="{Binding MyCommand}"/>
```

And the code behind:

```
MyCommand()
{
   int sel_item_1 = Angle[Angle.IndexOf(SelectedItem1)];
   SelectedItem1 = Angle[Angle.IndexOf(SelectedItem2)];
   SelectedItem2 = Angle[sel_item_1];
}
```

Comment: I guess this is a very good solution. I'm gonna try it. But I don't use the MVVM in this project... So that's why I used simple Button events.

Comment: Sure, if You don't care about MVVM, you can simply use `Events`.